# Verify $\liminf_{n\to\infty}[0,\frac{n}{1+n})=\limsup_{n\to\infty}[0,\frac{n}{1+n})=[0,1)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to verify the following.

$\liminf_{n\to\infty}[0,\frac{n}{1+n})=\limsup_{n\to\infty}[0,\frac{n}{1+n})=[0,1)$

Using the definition

$\liminf_{n\to\infty}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$

and

$lim\sup_{n\to\infty}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$

I tried to the following approach:

if $ x\in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}[0,\frac{k}{1+k})$ then $\exists n:\forall k \ge n, x<\frac{k}{1+k} $. As $n \to \infty$ so does $k$ in $ k \ge n$, hence $x<1$, and  $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}[0,\frac{k}{1+k})\subset [0,1)$

For the other direction i tried:

If $x<1$ then $0<1-x$, and by the Archmedian property $\exists k: 1/k<1-x$, but I could not manipulate this to $x<\frac{k}{1+k}$, so I can't go any further.

Any other kind of proof would also be much appreciated.

Thanks inadvance!

Comment: You have $\frac{1}{1+k} < \frac1k$, so $\frac{1}{1+k} < 1 - x \iff x < 1 - \frac{1}{1+k}$. But I'd think it would be easier to note that $A_k \subset A_{k+1}$ for all $k$. Then it is immediate.

Comment: Thanks, so simple! Yes $A_k \subset A_[k+1}$ but how do you construct a proof from there? I can "see" the answer intuitively, but trying to proove it as an exercise.

Comment: $A_k \subset A_{k+1}$ for all $k$ means $\bigcap\limits_{k=n}^\infty A_k = A_n$, and $\bigcup\limits_{k=n}^\infty A_k = A := \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty A_k$ independent of $n$.